# Porqué no se ven los estilos en mi página?

Tags: html, css3

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stilesheet" type="text/css"href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Marca</td>
        <td>Modelo</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="az">
      <td>Audi</td>
      <td>A3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="cel">
      <td>Audi</td>
      <td>A8</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="az">
      <td >Ford</td>
      <td>Fiesta</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="cel">
      <td>Peugeot</td>
      <td>306</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="az">
      <td >Peugeot</td>
      <td >1008</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
       <td colspan="2">Listado de coches</td>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

y la hoja de estilos:

```
table {
  width: 300px;
   text-align:center;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }

table, th, td {
border: 1 px solid black;
}

t foot, thead {
font-weight: bold;
background-color:orange;
}

.az{
  background-color: blue;
}

.cel{
  background-color: skyblue;

}
```

Comment: Al agregar tu código al snippet del sitio los estilos se ven que funcionan correctametne, ya revisaste la ruta? el archivo estilos.css está al lado de tu index.html? Otra cosa, en el valor del atributo rel de la etiqueta link tienes un error, debería ser stylesheet

Comment: He probado tu codigo en codepen y funciona perfectamente. Asegurate de poner la ruta CSS correctamente ya que creo que tienes el problema ahí. Adjunta una foto de tu directorio para hacernos una idea o dinos como los tienes colocados. Salu2!

Comment: ¿será que pusiste `rel="stilesheet"` y debería ser `rel="stylesheet"`?

Comment: Probablemente el archivo ".CSS" no está en la ubicación especificada en tu código, o el nombre del archivo no es el mismo, que estás pidiendo que te busque en ".html".

Comment: el valor del atributo rel en la linea 5 de tu archivo html tiene un valor incorrecto, solo corrigelo y ya esta Buena suerte ;D

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el tag link escribiste mal el rel, el atributo href está pegado al atributo anterior y en el CSS tfoot está mal escrito.

Así funciona bien:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
   text-align:center;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }

table, th, td {
border: 1 px solid black;
}

tfoot, thead {
font-weight: bold;
background-color:orange;
}

.az{
  background-color: blue;
}

.cel{
  background-color: skyblue;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Marca</td>
        <td>Modelo</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="az">
      <td>Audi</td>
      <td>A3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="cel">
      <td>Audi</td>
      <td>A8</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="az">
      <td >Ford</td>
      <td>Fiesta</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="cel">
      <td>Peugeot</td>
      <td>306</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="az">
      <td >Peugeot</td>
      <td >1008</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
       <td colspan="2">Listado de coches</td>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

¡Suerte!